# Can a Facebook Messenger Bot chat with two or more people in a group?

Tags: facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

Do all messenger bots interact directly with just one user at a time? Can a bot join a group of two or more people and talk to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently Facebook Messenger bots only work on a one to one basis.

One of the reasons is probably privacy.

Facebook are being very cautious before rolling out bots in a group context.

Answer (score 1):

Currently facebook does not allow to add bots in groups, however you can add bots in groups in Telegram.