# Facebook Page Messaging with multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

Is it possible to create a Facebook group chat with regular users and a Facebook Page using its messaging feature? If yes, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to chat with two or more people with a Facebook messenger bot.

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205889/can-a-facebook-messenger-bot-chat-with-two-or-more-people-in-a-group/40215053#40215053)